# JSPDF libraries for Html renderer?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf

what are the JSPDF libraries that are needed for html renderer ?

```
function savePdf() {
$.getScript('Scripts/jspdf.js', function savePdf1() {

    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
    doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
    doc.addPage();
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

    // Output as Data URI
    doc.output('datauri');

});
```

}

& how to use multiple Jspdf libraries in the above code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```